# Passing link with parameters with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this link:

```
<a id='delete' href='/add/delete.php?iid=XXXXX'>#</a>
```

And I want to pass it on through Jquery so the page doesn't refresh. However, I'm having a difficult time making that happen. All of the click events and ajax I've tried with Jquery have been unsuccessful.

Basically, I want the ajax to send delete.php the value in the iid parameter.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here try this the `href='1'` is the id you want to delete, also to replace the text it finds the `id="d1"`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $(".delete").click(function(e){
    var del_id = $(this).attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("/add/delete.php", { iid: del_id } ,function(data){
        //change the link to deleted
        $('#d'+del_id).replaceWith('<a href="#">Deleted</a>');
    });
  });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <a class='delete' id="d1" href='1'>Delete</a>
 <a class='delete' id="d2" href='2'>Delete</a>
 <a class='delete' id="d3" href='3'>Delete</a>
 <a class='delete' id="d4" href='4'>Delete</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works great! Thanks so much for the help. One final problem I'm having is that I want to remove the parent li element and all of its content. When I use $(this).closest('li').remove(); in the area you put the replaceWith code, nothing happens. Is that the wrong syntax? Below is my HTML code:
<li>
<div class='singleitem'>
<img src='/css/images/image.jpg' width='30' height='30' /><div id='listtext'><h1>title</h1></div>
<a class='delete' id='$iid' href='#'></a>
<div id='helper'></div>
</div>
</li>

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $("#delete").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("../add/delete.php", { iid: "xxx" } ,function(data){
       //do whatever with the result which is in the variable data.
       alert(data)
    });
  });
});
```

Since it is a delete, use POST. Otherwise some crawlers will crawl your delete page and you will see your tables are empty one fine morning.

**EDIT** : You can associate the value to be passed with the anchor tag in someway. Ex :Change your id tag to be in this format  del-YouIdTobe deleted ( Ex : del-1,del-2 etc..)

```
<a id='delete' href='#' id="del-1>Delte 1 </a>
<a id='delete' href='#' id="del-2>Delte 2 </a>
<a id='delete' href='#' id="del-3>Delte 3 </a>
```

Script

```
$(function(){
  $("#delete").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var val=$(this).attr("id").split("-")[0];
    $.post("../add/delete.php", { iid: val } ,function(data){
       //do whatever with the result which is in the variable data.
       alert(data)
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Since the XXXXX part of the parameter is changing from link to link, is there a way with Jquery to pull that parameter out of the link to pass along?