# Passing variables through URL with JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have this but is not working which is a mixed of both answers found here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369432/passing-link-with-parameters-with-jquery)... the alert message comes out empty and therefore the delete.php doesn't do anything

Any comments. I am using JQuery 1.8

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){

  $(".delete").click(function(e){
    var del_id = $(this).attr("id");
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("../folder/delete.php", { iid: del_id } ,function(data){
    alert(data)
        //change the link to deleted
        $('#'+del_id).replaceWith('<a href="#" class="delete">Deleted</a>');


    });
  });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <a class="delete" id="1" href='#'>Delete 1</a>
 <a class="delete" id="2" href='#'>Delete 2</a>
 <a class="delete" id="3" href='#'>Delete 3</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Delete.php is as follows:**

```
<?php 
    extract($_POST); 
    extract($_GET); 
    if ($del_id!=0){ 
        require_once("../includes/include.php"); 
        deleteItem($del_id); 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: show us code for delete.php

Comment: Put `var_dump($_POST);exit(1);` on top of your delete.php file, at least you'll see if your variables are set up correctly.

Comment: The delete.php is as follows:

<?php
extract($_POST);
extract($_GET);

if ($del_id!=0){
require_once("../includes/include.php");
deleteItem($del_id); 
}
?>

Comment: You are using `post` so data sent from the client to the server is in the `$_POST` array.

Comment: delete.php doesn't print anything, so what do you expect to see in `data`?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! First of all at the line alert(data) the window comes out empty with no values at all. And then at the delete.php does not do anything because it seems that the value for $del_id is undefined.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `extract()` with untrusted data like `$_POST` and `$_GET`.

Comment: @Jorge Have you read Sheikh Heera's answer? He explains why `$del_id` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, since the delete.php is not working I was trying everything but I am planning not to include those lines.

Comment: One more thing how could I place a confirmation before deleting in the JQuery script?

Answer (score 1):

You should change following line

```
if ($del_id!=0)
```

with this

```
if ($iid!=0)
```

because you are sending

```
{ iid: del_id } // iid is the variable
```

from the client side and `$iid` will be available in the `$_POST` so you can use without `extracting` the full `$_POST` array

```
if ($_POST['iid']!=0){...}
```

Also if you don't echo/print anything from the server side then you can't get back anything in the response.

Comment: Alternatively, you can change the `$.post` parameter to `{ del_id: del_id }`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I already tried also with if ($_POST['iid']!=0){...} and doesn't do anything or print anything.

Comment: You must use `echo/print` from the server to send it back in the response, if you use `echo "OK"` then you'll get `OK` in the `data`.

Comment: It was my mistake. I was missing something at the delete.php file and now is working! Thanks for taking your time to help me out! Have a great day! Worked with if ($_POST['iid']!=0){...}

Comment: One more thing how could I place a confirmation before deleting in the JQuery script?